# How do I make several nodes line up and move up when the first one is removed? (GDscript)

Tags: position, nodes, gdscript

I'm making a clicker in Godot, and I want the upgrades to line up in a way so that once you buy an upgrade, the next upgrade(or node) moves up to fill in the position. It's kind of hard to explain it, but I think you should get the gist of it. As a beginner programmer, I have no clue how to do that.

I haven't tried anything yet, since I have no idea where to start.

For clearer examples, consider 3 nodes, and the positions being (0,0), (1,0), and (2,0).
(I will edit those positions later if I need them)

The first one is at (0,0) and when the first node is removed, the second one takes its place, and the third node takes the second node's place etc.
Also when I mean disappear/removed, I just mean probably once you've clicked on it with the right amount of resources, (clicker game) it runs its code and it sets visibility to false.

Comment: Usually you bring programming questions to this site once you have run into an issue with your implementation. Edit: I'm going to point you to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ which will take game development question that do not have to be programming related.

Answer (score 0):

A [`VBoxContainer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/es/4.x/classes/class_vboxcontainer.html) will have the behaviour you describe. `Container`s will ignore hidden `Control`s, and `VBoxContainer` that will organize its children vertically (i.e. in a column).

You might also want the `Control`s to steadily move up. You could archive that using a [tween](https://docs.godotengine.org/es/4.x/classes/class_tween.html) to reduce the size of the `Control` you are about to hide. *However, I would like to encourge you to focus on making it functional first.*

I'll also remind you to set the [`disable`](https://docs.godotengine.org/es/4.x/classes/class_basebutton.html#class-basebutton-property-disabled) property of `Button`s when they should not be clickable.